# Vehicle safety dataset

Tags: data-request

I’m working on an assignment for school about vehicle safety and I’ve found some useful summary statistics about traffic accident data in general but I’m specifically looking for studies into the effectiveness of driver assist technologies in reducing accident/fatality rates.

A dataset showing the following would be useful

- type of cars involved in accidents
- driver assist / not
- outcome of incident - injury/fatality

Even if you could just point me in the direction of a place where I can find detailed studies that would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UK Road Safety: Traffic Accidents and Vehicles](https://www.kaggle.com/tsiaras/uk-road-safety-accidents-and-vehicles?select=Vehicle_Information.csv)

Detailed dataset of road accidents and involved vehicles in the UK (2005-2017)

The dataset comprises of two csv files:

- AccidentInformation.csv: every line in the file represents a unique traffic accident (identified by the AccidentIndex column), featuring various properties related to the accident as columns. Date range: 2005-2017
- Vehicle_Information.csv: every line in the file represents the involvement of a unique vehicle in a unique traffic accident, featuring various vehicle and passenger properties as columns. Date range: 2004-2016

---

[Aggressive Driving Data](https://www.kaggle.com/veeralakrishna/aggressive-driving-data)

Aggressive driving can have a very bad outcome.

---

[Motor Vehicle Safety Data](https://datahub.io/JohnSnowLabs/motor-vehicle-safety-data)

The dataset contains information on the motor vehicle fatalities on U.S. roads with number of fatalities, crashes, number of injured persons and miles covered by vehicles. National Transportation Statistics presents statistics on the U.S. transportation system, including its physical components, safety record, economic performance, the human and natural environment, and national security. Transportation's safety record, giving data on accidents, crashes, fatalities, and injuries for each transportation mode and hazardous materials. Compiled and published by the U.S. Department of Transportation's Bureau of Transportation Statistics (BTS), National Transportation Statistics presents information on the U.S. transportation system, including its physical components, safety record, economic performance, energy use, and environmental impacts.

---

[BUREAU OF TRANSPORTATION STATISTICS(BTS](https://www.bts.gov/content/motor-vehicle-safety-data))

U.S. Department of Transportation

Answer (score 0):

The Highway Loss Data Institute (HLDI) in the U.S. is supported by the insurance companies and has details for items such as [advanced driver assist](https://www.iihs.org/topics/advanced-driver-assistance). They are in some ways ahead of the NTSB in how and what they test. You may need to reach out to them directly to get a raw data export, or just scrape.

Comment: Thanks dude! I upvoted your answer but I don't have enough reputation for it to show, I nonetheless appreciate it though!